# Error C# No overload for method 'PlayClipAtPoint' takes 0 arguments

Tags: c#

Ive got an error that is called : no overload for method 'PlayClipAtPoint' takes 0 arguments.
It is really annoying because i just fixed the other issue and now this one appeared.

Comment: the double { at the end were because of ctrl and k here lol

Comment: Read what the error message says carefully. It doesn't take 0 arguments, so you have to pass arguments. Considering it's called PlayClipAtPoint, I assume it takes a point...

Comment: Sure enough, there's [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint.html).

Answer (score 2):

The static method `AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint()` takes at least two parameters - a clip and vector. Check the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/355/Documentation/ScriptReference/AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint.html).

You would need to write something like:

```
AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(audioClip, Vector3(5,1,2));
```